# Differences between zookeeper-server-start.sh and kafka-server-start.sh

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Is one of them more recommended/preferred to use than the other?

Comment: Not clear why you think one is recommended over the other. The documentation states both are required. Zookeeper before Kafka

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kafka uses Zookeeper so you **must** start a Zookeeper server before starting the Kafka broker. Zookeeper and Kafka broker are two distinct things and both of them are required in order to run a Kafka Cluster. Kafka is a distributed system and is built to use Zookeeper which is responsible for controller election, topic configuration, clustering etc.

In order to run Zookeeper you need to set the parameters in the configuration file `config/zookeeper.properties` and then start the ZK server using

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Then you need to run at least one Kafka broker which can be configured in `config/server.properties` file and then start it using

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

Zookeeper-server-start.sh is to start your zookeeper server which by default runs on port 2181.

To use kafka brokers, topics and partition you need to have your zookeeper server running, zookeeper works as manager for kafka brokers.

Kafka-server-start.sh is to start your kafka broker.

`Zookeeper-server-start.sh`takes a 
`zookeeper.properties`file for the configuration

`Kafka-server-start` takes a Kafka 
`server.properties` file for configuration